# Why is the gate phisically bigger than the inversion layer in a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

In other words why does the gate overlap a bit of the source and drain instead of being exactly on the middle, please look on the following diagram

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baTkm.png]

You can clearly see that L is smaller than the gate length, why is this? When doing calculations we ignore the differences and say that they're equal but in reality, it is not equal.

Comment: That's a simplified diagram. But what do you imagine here about the fringing field? Edge effects?

Comment: @jonk Ah, I see, so we want a perfectly perpendicular field at least at the inversion layer, correct?

Comment: I don't think anyone cares about perfection. But certainly you should be able to see issues arising as high-K or shrinking feature sizes along certain axes are considered.

Comment: The amount of overlap from the gate to the source/drain depends on the manufacturing method. This looks a little like a homework or quiz question, so I will just give you a hint: "self-aligned gate"

Comment: Think about what would happen if the gate was less wide than "L" in that drawing.